# Kendo Grid bug on huge amount of data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm fetching large data amount to my Kendo Grid, they can reach 700,000 rows. And then I'm facing a bug in the dataSource -> parse method, the (response) object is null.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    ....
    schema: {
        parse: function(response) {
            // response is NULL
        }
    }
}
```

I know I should implement server side data processing (which needs a lot of time to fulfill filtering, sorting..etc), that's why I'm thinking of a quick workaround for now.

And, why does that happen? Is there any Kendo limitation there?

Comment: Anything in the console log or network tab ?  Did the query timeout ?What is your server side technology ? Do the server side logs indicate what happened during the query ? Do you have other client apps in your organization that can handle 700K rows from remote server ? Kendo grid is not really designed for one big data dump. Really best to do what you know you should and then things like paging or virtual scrolling and filtering are easy wins.

Comment: I don't think there is a limitation on the number of rows a Kendo Grid can have, but there are limitations on how much the browser can handle. For example, Chrome may be able to handle more rows than IE or vice versa. It just depends on how much is in each row. Either way, you would need a really good reason for needing to load 700k rows at once.

Comment: @Richard, console log is clean except an exception of (response) object is undefined. No timeout (200 OK response code) and data is in the response, ASP.NET Core, yes, maybe I'm going to start implementing pagination.. thanks

Comment: You should be able to set breakpoints in VS and step through the server side method that is not delivering, or having murky issues causing it to return null.  Happy coding!

Comment: @Richard Server side returns data correctly, I can see them also in chrome F12 Network tab, that was the strange part.. Any way, I managed today to implement server side data processing and life is good, thanks